# Polish Character Set in HTML page

Tags: html, unicode, fonts

I'm trying to use Polish Character Set in my [website](http://marekzurek.com), but it doesn't work as expected. Do you have any pieces of advice? Is it possible with default fonts?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics to ask] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Maybe you saved your HTML file in a non-UTF-8 format which may cause some of the Unicode characters to not show correctly.  https://www.w3.org/International/questions/qa-changing-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reviewed your website and seems like you have a file encoding issue. I'm not familiar with Polish Character Set but I used to design a website in Farsi which gave me same issues when I saved my files in any format other than UTF-8.

It seems like your `index.html` file saved as `iso-8859-1` instead of `utf-8`. Try to open your file in your editor and save it as a new file and specify to be UTF-8.

Also, your website is based on a template from ThemeForest, so you can simply ask this question from the original Author and see if other people had the same issue.